# Query how much a Entry has been used

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working with an Oracle database and Oracle SQL Developer 4

I'm looking for a way to find out if an ID has been used or not on multiple tables which I joined with a union. This should be a column named `HAS_BEEN_USED` with the values "Yes" if it has been used once or more in one of the tables and "No" if it hasn't been used in any of them.

> If the ID appears once in any of the tables: HAS_BEEN_USED = YES
>
> If not: HAS_BEEN_USED = NO

Something like this:

```
SELECT PRICETITLEID, IF(PRICETITLEID>0, 'Yes', 'No') AS HAS_BEEN_USED FROM ZZPRICETITLE
UNION
SELECT PRICETITLEID, IF(COUNT(PRICETITLEID)>0, 'Yes', 'No') AS HAS_BEEN_USED FROM ZZEXTVALUATIONRULE
UNION
SELECT PRICETITLEID, IF(COUNT(PRICETITLEID)>0, 'Yes', 'No') AS HAS_BEEN_USED FROM ZZMARKET
UNION
SELECT PRICETITLEID, IF(COUNT(PRICETITLEID)>0, 'Yes', 'No') AS HAS_BEEN_USED FROM ZZMARKETUSE
UNION
SELECT PRICETITLEID, IF(COUNT(PRICETITLEID)>0, 'Yes', 'No') AS HAS_BEEN_USED FROM ZZPRICE
WHERE TIMECREATED >= '01-FEB-17' 
GROUP BY PRICETITLEID;
```

Comment any questions

Thanks

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT PRICETITLEID, CASE WHEN PRICETITLEID>0 THEN "Yes" ELSE "No" END AS HAS_BEEN_USED FROM ZZPRICETITLE
UNION
SELECT PRICETITLEID, CASE WHEN COUNT(PRICETITLEID)>0 THEN "Yes" ELSE "No" END AS HAS_BEEN_USED FROM ZZEXTVALUATIONRULE
UNION
SELECT PRICETITLEID, CASE WHEN COUNT(PRICETITLEID)>0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS HAS_BEEN_USED FROM ZZMARKET
UNION
SELECT PRICETITLEID, CASE WHEN COUNT(PRICETITLEID)>0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS HAS_BEEN_USED FROM ZZMARKETUSE
UNION
SELECT PRICETITLEID, CASE WHEN COUNT(PRICETITLEID)>0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS HAS_BEEN_USED FROM ZZPRICE
WHERE TIMECREATED >= '01-FEB-17' 
GROUP BY PRICETITLEID;
```

Comment: You may also need to add a group by to each of your selects where you are doing the count